# Extracting images from camera video at predetermined intervals

Tags: python, opencv

I have the code to get images from the video stream of a laptop camera. I want to reduce the photo saving interval to one photo per minute. The original code looks like this

```
# Importing all necessary libraries 
import cv2 
import os 

# Read the video from specified path 
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

try: 

    # creating a folder named data 
    if not os.path.exists('data'): 
        os.makedirs('data') 

# if not created then raise error 
except OSError: 
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data') 

# frame 
currentframe = 0

while(True): 

    # reading from frame 
    ret,frame = cam.read() 

    if ret: 
        # if video is still left continue creating images 
        name = './data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
        print ('Creating...' + name) 

        # writing the extracted images 
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame) 

        # increasing counter so that it will 
        # show how many frames are created 
        currentframe += 1
    else: 
        break

# Release all space and windows once done 
cam.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For this task I try to use the parameter `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC`

```
[...]
# Read the video from specified path 
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,20000)
[...]

while(True): 
[...]    
        # writing the extracted images 
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
        cv2.waitKey() 
[...]
```

But, the saving speed remains the same and I see the following error

> videoio error v4l2 property pos_msec is not supported

I use Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.7, and OpenCV 4.1.

Where do I have a mistake, and whether I chose the right way to minimize the load on my computer's resources?

**UPD**

Using the recommendation of J.D. this code is working

```
import cv2
import os

import time

prev_time = time.time()
delay = 1 # in seconds
# Read the video from specified path
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
currentframe = 0

while (True):
    # reading from frame
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if ret:
        if time.time() - prev_time > delay:
            # if video is still left continue creating images
            name = './data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
            print('Creating...' + name)
            # writing the extracted images
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
            currentframe += 1
            prev_time = time.time()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: does it work without interval?

Comment: might want to reduce the capture rate (maybe via `cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS`) down so that you're throwing less frames away

Comment: @SamMason your way works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** this answer is not a good solution - due to the frame buffer, as described in the comments. Because of the relevant information in the comments I will leave the answer.

If you don't plan to expand the code to do other things, you can just use the waitkey:

`cv2.waitKey(60000)` will freeze code execution 60 secs.

If you want to expand the code, you have to create a time based loop:

```
import time

prev_time = time.time()
count = 0
delay = 1 # in seconds

while True:
    if time.time()-prev_time > delay:
        count += 1
        print(count)
        prev_time = time.time()
```

Comment: I think this is incorrect. I believe OpenCV buffers 4-5 images, so you will get old data if you do that.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, but you can reduce the size of the buffer down to one image.  you'd then need to pull two images from the camera (first would be old data, the second would be current)

Comment: @MarkSetchell I wasn't aware. Does it buffer every read, or only on startup? If so, would looping the first 5 images be an option?

Comment: @SamMason Yes, you can, I don't dispute that. I was just saying that the answer is probably not going to produce the desired result *"as is"*.  Another option is maybe to call `grab()` https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-grab to discard the frames.

Comment: I believe it buffers all reads, not just at startup. Looping and reading 5 images is also not ideal, because the buffer size may change in some future version and you may not realise. I believe the safer option is to `grab()` continuously and only `retrieve()` when necessary. I may be wrong - I have been before!!! :-) If anyone knows better, I am always very happy to be corrected!

Comment: @MarkSetchell agreed, was just trying to help make the answer more useful.  `grab` looks useful.  you can use `CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE` to change the number of buffered frames

Comment: Also, reading and discarding is not ideal - not so much on USB, but especially when using a network camera and dragging large video frames across a network unnecessarily is ill-advised.

Comment: Am I right to understand that time delays are better implemented with built-in python than with the opencv library?

Comment: Not necessarily, I just whipped up a possible approach. As the comments state it may not be an appropriate one, but most important is that it works for your application.

Answer (score 0):

you should read separately and set the values again for each image, like this:

```
while(True): 
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,20000)
    # reading from frame 
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    if ret: 
        # if video is still left continue creating images 
        name = './data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
        print ('Creating...' + name) 
        # writing the extracted images 
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame) 
        cv2.waitKey() 
        # increasing counter so that it will 
        # show how many frames are created 
        currentframe += 1        
    else: 
        break
    cam.release()
```

and check your openCV version for python about the error.